# Javascript with callback function not working

Tags: javascript

Here is my javascript program and it supposed to output the alert statement at the bottom of the code but is not apppearing. Why is it?

```
//function mean
function mean(values, callback) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, max = values.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            total += callback(value[i]);
        } else {
            total += values[i];
        }
    }
}

var result = mean([2, 5, 7, 11, 4], function (x) {
    return 2 * x;
});

alert("The result mean is " + result + ".");
```

Comment: `total += callback(value[i]);` -- should be `values` not `value`. Keep your browser console open so that you can see errors reported.

Comment: Value is not defined

Comment: check your console for errors in JavaScript

Comment: You have to write values[i] and return the variable total in order to get a result other than undefined.,

Comment: You can answer that question yourself if you [learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/). Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: You're not doing anything with your `total`. Perhaps you should return something from the `mean` function so it can be outputted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return `total` and change `value`to `values`.

```js
function mean(values, callback) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, max = values.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            total += callback(values[i]);
        } else {
            total += values[i];
        }
    }
    return total;
}

var result = mean([2, 5, 7, 11, 4], function (x) {
    return 2 * x;
});

alert("The result mean is " + result + ".");
```

You can rewrite the code to a more compact way:

```js
function mean(values, callback) {
    callback = callback || function (x) { return x; };
    return values.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + callback(a);
    }, 0);
}

var result = mean([2, 5, 7, 11, 4], function (x) {
    return 2 * x;
});

alert("The result mean is " + result + ".");
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with the typo mentioned by Pointy, If I am reading it right, you never return a value from mean, try returning total

Answer (score 0):

You have to return total in your callback function and make sure values variables are not typed as value.